# Accessing vuex modules data from within a plugin

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I am moving some data from the vuex store into its own module.  Most of it works great, but I'm running into an issue that I can't seem to fix.

I have a plugin that I add, and that plugin also needs access to the store.
So at the top of that plugin, we import the store:

```
import store from '../store/store';
```

great - further down that plugin, I'm accessing the data of the store in a method that I expose on the service:

```
hasPermission(permission) {
    return (store.state.authorization.permissions.indexOf(permission) >= 0);
}
```

Please note authorization is now a seperate module, and is no longer part of the root state object.

now the funny thing is that the above will return an error telling me indexOf is not a function.
When I add the following, however:

```
hasPermission(permission) {
    console.log('Validating permission ' + permission);
    console.log(store.state);
    return (store.state.authorization.permissions.indexOf(permission) >= 0);
}
```

I notice that (1) the output to console is what I expect it to be, and (2), I'm not getting the error, and my menu structure dynamically builds as expected...

so I'm a bit confused to say the least...

authorization.permissions is updated each time a user authenticates, logs out, or chooses another account to work on; in these cases we fetch updated permissions from the server and commit it to the store, so we can build our menu structure based on up-to-date permissions.  Works pretty good, but I'm not sure I understand why this fails to be honest.

The plugin is created as follows in the install:

```
Vue.prototype.$security = new Vue(
    ...
    methods: {
        hasPermission: function(permission) {
            ...
        }
    }
    ...
);
```

Comment: Can we see the code for the plugin? How is `hasPersmission` added to Vue? Also, what is the initial state of `state.authorization`?

Comment: I'll update the question.

Comment: I expect at some point `authorization.permissions` is not an array.

Comment: well yes, but how do you explain that it works when I first do a console.log of the exact same authorization.permissions?  I don't get it.

Comment: `console.log` is not necessarily synchronous. Set a breakpoint there instead.

Comment: okay, but do you see anything that I shouldn't be doing in my setup?  It is as if the modules aren't already loaded when hasPermission is accessed, which is weird though, as the store is already active a few seconds before I'm getting to the hasPermission (I would need to login first before I hit that logic for the first time)

Comment: It's difficult to speculate without a working example. I'm not sure why you don't just add the store to the `$security` Vue object the same way you would with any other Vue, but I don't know that that is your issue. Seems likely something is asynchronously populating your data and that isn't done before hasPermission is called.

Comment: Hi Bert - maybe I should do it like that - let me try how that works!

Comment: Bert - you literally saved my life. I never realised it, but you're right - a plugin is just another Vue instance being created, so I was in fact able to register store so I could then use this.$store.state in the plugin

Comment: Technically, a plugin isn't anything other than an object with an install function that accepts the Vue object and some options; in this case you are specifically creating a new root Vue in the plugin, but I don't know that it's necessary. If, for example, the plugin is mainly a collection of methods, it might be more appropriate to use a mixin. The only reason I would create a separate Vue instance is if I legitimately wanted a separate reactive data store.

Comment: I was just discussing this with someone else, and the general idea is to make sure that the plugin keeps all of its data, methods etc seperated.  For instance, we have a plugin that we use as a layer above Laravel Echo (automatically disconnedting and reconnecting sesions for instance); we register it under Vue.propotype.$ws (for websockets), and that basically gives me a bunch of methods under this.$ws.dosomething().  It's better than a mixin because I don't need to always mix it in - it is just available throughout.  Unless you have arguments not to do like that? :-)
Anyway - THANK YOU.